# Module not found - ng-uikit-pro-standard

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use datatables in Angular with material. I'm using this [link for reference.](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/tables/datatables/#advanced-table-options) In that tutorial, they are importing `MdbTableDirective`, `MdbTablePaginationComponent`, `MdbTableService` from `ng-uikit-pro-standard`. I'm using Angular 7. Whenever I run my code, I always get this error.

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng-uikit-pro-standard'.

According to [this link](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/angular/not-found-ng-uikit-pro-standard/), `ng-uikit-pro-standard` doesn't yet support Angular 7. But according to this [link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/), `Material Design for Bootstrap (Angular version)` is built on `Angular 7, Bootstrap 4 and TypeScript.` How can I add this `ng-uikit-pro-standard` module?

Comment: Anyone here who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Just to clear a few things up:

There is [Material design](https://material.io/), made by Google and it is a **platform-independent [design system](https://envato.com/blog/introduction-material-design/)**.

It's most used implementation is the official (=made by the Angular team) lib, the [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) **Component libary**.

What you are using is a third solution, totally different, and is based on **Bootstrap** - that means, it is not only different, but it is built on Bootstrap 4 and jQuery, as the site suggests.

If you want to learn **Angular Material**, I strongly suggest you do so with the official component libary to avoid these situations. Also: using Bootstrap + jQuery to achive Material desing feels [highly](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-I-prefer-material-design-over-Bootstrap) [unnecessary](https://github.com/nefe/You-Dont-Need-jQuery).  Use bootstrap based lib for bootstrap, material based for material...

**To solve your current problem:** I suspect you did not install the `ng-uikit-pro-standard` properly. Try running `npm install mdbootstrap` as the [site suggests.](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/download/)

Comment: That `npm install mdbootstrap` command didn't help. I'm getting same error.

Comment: did you include it in `app.module.ts` imports?

Comment: I didn't get you, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Try npm install ng-uikit-pro-standard

Comment: Learn to use code formatting for more readability.